# Can't change the value of a attribute of a SVG Path with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, svg, snap.svg

I created a SVG path using snap.svg you can see the code of it down bellow. Now I am trying to cdhange the value of the Attributes for example the strokeWidth. For this i created a text input box and a button that runs a function which should fill in a new value for the strokeWidth. But it does not work. What am i doing wrong? Is it possible that i can't even change the value ? I also posted the code for the input box and the button + my function for changing the strokewidth down bellow

I tried a lot of different functions and scripts but none seemed to work. Sometimes I got an error message sometimes not. When i got an error message it always said that either the function is not defined or L_PUF_WAR is not defined.

````
var L_PUF_WAR = s.path("m 937.88689,516.10127 v -51.8831 H 573.37482 V 340.49692 H 391.11879 V 276.6408").attr({
                        fill: "none",
                        stroke: "#bada55",
                        strokeWidth: 15,
                        strokeDasharray: "30, 30 ,30"
                    });
                    A_PUF.append(L_PUF_WAR);```
````

```
    <script>
        function hallo(){
            var number = document.getElementById("number").value;
            if(number > 0){
                L_PUF_WAR.strokeWidth = number;
            }
        }
    </script>
        <input type="text" id="number" name="number"/><br/>  
        <input type="button" value="breite" onclick="hallo()"/>
```

```
I am expecting to put in a value for the strokewidth into the Input Box for example 20 and then the strokeWidth should change to that value..
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `.setAttribute()`:

```
L_PUF_WAR.setAttribute("strokeWidth", number);
```

Comment: also tried that but then I get this error ```Cannot read property 'attr' of undefined
    at hallo (index.html:197)
    at HTMLInputElement.onclick (index.html:203)
```

Comment: What is the scope of `L_PUF_WAR`?

Comment: what do you mean with scope?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript

Comment: if I add this. infront of the ```L_PUF_WAR.strokeWidth = number;``` it says that it cant read property 'attr' of undefined at hallo(). And it should be a global scope